# delete columns where values are not increasing in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a df with values and some columns have values which are increasing and some columns have values which are either decreasing or not changing. I want to delete those columns. I tried to use is_monotonic but that returns a boolean = TRUE if the values are increasing but does not include if the values remain the same

```
data = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c':33}, {'a':10, 'b': 2, 'c': 30}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

In the above example i want to keep only column 'a' as the other two columns are the same or decreasing values. can anyone help me please?

Comment: `df.loc[:, ~(df.diff() <= 0).any(0)]` ..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get difference of all columns, remove first only NaNs row and compare if all values are greater like `0`:

```
df = df.loc[:, df.diff().iloc[1:].gt(0).all()]
print (df)
    a
0   1
1  10
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.diff())
     a    b    c
0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  9.0  0.0 -3.0

print (df.diff().iloc[1:])
     a    b    c
1  9.0  0.0 -3.0

print (df.diff().iloc[1:].gt(0))
      a      b      c
1  True  False  False

print (df.diff().iloc[1:].gt(0).all())
a     True
b    False
c    False
dtype: bool
```

Or like mentioned in comments change logic - get any columns if les or equal 0 and change mask by `~`:

```
df = df.loc[:, ~df.diff().le(0).any()]
```

Comment: @ChrisA - Sure, if sometimes not, let me know